# Setting MQ flags for reading segmented message with API exit

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to set flags for seamlessly reading segmented message with GetBefore Exit call, like below:

```
(*ppGetMsgOpts)->Options = MQGMO_WAIT | MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE | MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG | (*ppGetMsgOpts)->Options;
```

It works perfectly well if I use rfhutil as reading client, the whole message is read at once, even if it was stored segmented. 
But when I try to read with JMS client, it ends up with the following error code:

```
'2046' ('MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR')
```

MQ log gives no clue, only tells about "internal error".

Could it be possible at all to read such message with JMS client?
Even if not, what could be a particular problem with options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message segmentation is a Messaging Provider specific feature and is not defined in JMS specification. Hence you have to use provider specific APIs, MQ base Java classes for example, to get segmented messages.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve, is to make messages travelling between 2 remote QMs segmented, to make such transfer more reliable on unstable channels. Is there a way to do that with exit API, taking that end client are JMS ones? Or I anyway I have to use some MQI client reading from intermediate queue and gathering segments together?

Comment: Sorry, I did notice your comment earlier. What message sizes are we looking at here and why you think segmentation would solve the problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: We use the maximum possible, so our messages could are up to 100M. But we expect some troubles with transferring such big messages between remote hosts, those are distributed geographically and having unstable network channels in some cases. Transferring segmented messages could be of some help in such cases, am I right?

Comment: Yes, some segments could get transferred before channels end due network issues. Your best is to use provider specific API to segment messages as JMS APIs do not offer that facility.